# Routine (get_data_type) can not be resolved

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I've just updated the informix jdbc driver on my application (from 3.0 to V4.10.JC4DE) and the following error occurred, when trying to connect with informix 9.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Routine (get_data_type) can not be resolved.
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3130)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.D(IfxSqli.java:3412)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2325)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2250)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1485)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeStatementQuery(IfxSqli.java:1465)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet.a(IfxResultSet.java:211)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQueryImpl(IfxStatement.java:1064)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeQuery(IfxStatement.java:236)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(IfxDatabaseMetaData.java:3549)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(NewProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:3968)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata.initColumns(TableMetadata.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata.<init>(TableMetadata.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.getTableMetadata(DatabaseMetadata.java:113)
    ... 54 more
```

The new driver works fine with Informix 11. Unfortunately, I have to support connection with Informix 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Informix 9 is a very very old engine. I think you should upgrade (or tell your clients to upgrade) to a newer - and supported - version. A simple upgrade should give them lots of new features, better performance (at least 40% more), and of course, a more stable engine.

Actually it really does not support version 9. On the product Release Notes page, you will see that:

"To use IBM Informix JDBC Driver to connect to an IBM Informix database, you must use one of the following IBM Informix database servers:

```
Version 11.50, 11.70, or 12.10
IBM Informix Extended Parallel Server, Version 8.3 or later
```

"

Comment: The versio upgrade was unevitable, thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when trying to make the procedure call return an Object for testing

Instead, create a projection interface for the output and have the function return that.

Jpa interface projection: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#1-closed-projections

Doesn't work:

```java
public interface AnyInterface extends JpaRepository<Entity,Pk> {
  @Procedure("procedure_name")
  Object doProcedure(@Param("param1") String name);
}
```

Worked:

```java
public interface AnyInterface extends JpaRepository<Entity,Pk> {
  @Procedure("procedure_name")
  ProjectionOutput doProcedure(@Param("param1") String name);
}
```

and in the controller, annotate the function calling `repo.doProcedure(string)` with
`@Transactional(readOnly = true)`
from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation`
to deal with this error:

> You're trying to execute a @Procedure method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the ResultSet can actually be consumed. Make sure the consumer code uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.